# OpenModelica adding data

Tags: openmodelica

I'm new to working with modelica and ran into problems quickly.
I am trying to simulate heating systems of buildings. I already have the dynamic heat load that is required for each building in an excel table for one year in kwh. I am now trying to implicate this data into my model but I cant figure out how.
Can someone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you expand on this with some code so we can see and help with it. Thanks :-) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Adding my complete code would be too long.. I am working with the buidlings library and have multiple boilers covering the heat load of different buidlings which I want to integrate somehow without having to model the buildings because I already have the dynamic loads in excel